# javascript prototype errors

Tags: ajax, http

i am sending ajax requests after 5 seconds
and i have 3 types of requests to send
but after few request it starts errrors
401 access denied
501

how to overcome dis

Comment: You should add some more details/example code. Now you are basically asking 'I have an error, how to solve it?' Which is quite hard to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are not receiving JavaScript errors.  You are receiving HTTP errors.  Ensure your address is correct and then verify you are not being denied by configurations on the server.